# How to make C code to MISRA C:2012 compliance?

Tags: c, embedded, misra

I am validating MISRA C:2012 standard to my MCU code using PC-Lint.
I got following errors.Here I posted a sample code where I got errors on condition statements.

1] unsigned integer literal without a 'U' suffix [MISRA 2012 Rule 7.2, required] S_LCB_100,

2] side effects on right hand of logical operator, '&&' [MISRA 2012 Rule 13.5, required]
                        while(( 0x00000000 != List[Loop] ) && ( 0 != Counter ))

3] : a signed value and an unsigned value cannot be used together as operands to != [MISRA 2012 Rule 10.4, required]
                        while(( 0x00000000 != List[Loop] ) && ( 0 != Counter ))

4]  : a signed value and an unsigned value cannot be used together as operands to != [MISRA 2012 Rule 10.4, required]  while(( 0x00000000 != List[Loop] ) && ( 0 != Counter ))

5] an unsigned value and a signed value cannot be used together as operands to == [MISRA 2012 Rule 10.4, required] if ( List[Loop] == 0x00000000 )

**How can I make it MISRA C:2012 compliance?**

```
typedef unsigned char UINT8;
typedef unsigned char BYTE;  
typedef unsigned long int UINT32; 
#define S_LCB_100 0xF0BB12DE;
#define MULTI 0x1A;
volatile static BYTE Counter = 0;
static UINT8 Loop = 0;    
static UINT32 List[]=  
{
    S_LCB_100,
    0x00000000,
};
while(( 0x00000000 != List[Loop] ) && ( 0 != Counter ))
{
 .......some code
}
if ( List[Loop] == 0x00000000 )
{
.....some code
}
```

Comment: I don't think this code will compile. The `;` on the end of macro constant definition `#define S_LCB_100 0xF0BB12DE;` looks straight like an error. Also such constants usually should have suffix `ll` or `lu` to fit it in the type.

Comment: Before worrying about the clever stuff, deal with Directive 3.1 - All code shall compile without errors...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

General remarks:

- Before worrying about MISRA-C compliance, get the code to compile on a C compiler.
- Then make sure you have the MISRA-C:2012 document available or you simply cannot work with MISRA.
- Get rid of nonsense like "Yoda conditions".
- Get rid of custom typedefs and use `stdint.h`. If you are on C90 then `typedef` with the names used by `stdint.h`.

> 1] unsigned integer literal without a 'U' suffix [MISRA 2012 Rule 7.2, required] S_LCB_100,

Pretty self-explaining. Add `U` or `u` to integer constants that should be unsigned. Read rule 7.2 for details.

> 2] side effects on right hand of logical operator, '&&' [MISRA 2012 Rule 13.5, required] while(( 0x00000000 != List[Loop] ) && ( 0 != Counter ))

`Counter` is voltatile-qualified and accessing it is a side-effect. So it should not exist inside complex expressions in general, and particularly not on the right hand side of a boolean && expression - that's quite questionable code. In this case you could simply rewrite the code as this:

```
uint32_t count = (uint32_t)Counter;

while((count != 0u) && (List[Loop] != 0u))
{
  ...
  count = (uint32_t)Counter; // read volatile variable in an expression of its own
}
```

> 3] a signed value and an unsigned value cannot be used together as operands to != [MISRA 2012 Rule 10.4, required] while(( 0x00000000 != List[Loop] ) && ( 0 != Counter ))

This is because `Counter` is declared as `BYTE`. Drop all such home-brewed crap types and declare it as `uint8_t` instead. Then use the `while` form as shown above. Use `u` suffix. This should fix 2) to 5).

Comment: While you are technically correct about the side effect, I bet that more logical (and therefore invisible to MISRA) errors are introduced by such helper variables than there are systems which fail on the non-executed side effect.

Comment: @Vroomfondel Hardly. Just pick any hardware peripheral of a MCU and write a driver using its memory-mapped registers. Unintended read/write will cause havoc. MISRA's roots are such embedded systems.

Comment: If someone is trashing around in memory mapped registers by the use of volatile he/she doesn't deserve better. ´volatile´ may have been intended for simple HW access but over the years the committee groked that it wouldn't be able to foresee every quirky access method and so at least in C90/C99 the standard definition doesn't deliver the HW meaning of "Buddy, really, access this like I wrote it, or else..."

Comment: @Vroomfondel Every single hardware register definition uses `volatile`, in 99.999% of all embedded systems written in C.

Comment: @Lundin  Yes., first compiled my code then only I am starting to make it MISRA Compliance.

Comment: @Lundin how about if I want to compare like if(data[0] == MC) where //MC is a defined macro with hex value like #define MC 0xAC  and data[0] is an uint8_t type varibale. I have to add u to all defined macros which I am comparing with unsigned varibales?

Comment: @Ludin what is the guarantee that `count` dose not get optimized by compiler?As it may see `Counter` is not getting updated in the loop.

Comment: @raj123 The posted code does not compile in C. The macros have semicolons etc. Regarding the macro, then yes, the correct way is to define it as `#define MC 0xACu`, then you can use it together with an `uint8_t` and be MISRA compliant. Otherwise bad bugs might happen. Consider for example `(~MC + u8) >> n;`. If "MC" is a signed literal like `0xAC`, this code may give an unexpected result due to arithmetic shift on some compilers. But if it is unsigned `0xACu`, that bug will never happen.

Comment: @Vagish The guarantee is that a compiler may not optimize away reads/writes to a volatile-qualified variable. C17 5.1.2.3 §4 and §6. Since it is volatile, it is updated each time the right operator of `&&` is evaluated. The bug here is that the variable is not updated when the operator containing its access is not evaluated.

Comment: Why is that a "bug"? The volatile variable is accessed by a read. This is completely ok - even under the standard "what constitutes an access is implementation defined" wording.

Comment: @Vroomfondel Because volatile variables are either hardware registers or shared sensitive variables. They should be read deterministically, not "sometimes". Either you need to read them or you don't. Notably, the bug could as well be that this variable shouldn't be volatile qualified in the first place, we can't tell.