# How to resolve MISRA C:2012 Rule 13.2 and 13.3 for C code?

Tags: c, embedded, misra

I have C source code and I am making it MISRA Compliant. I got an following errors related to MISRA 2012 Rule 13.3 and 13.2:

1. increment/decrement operation combined with other operation with side-effects [MISRA 2012 Rule 13.3, advisory]buf[count++] = U1RXREG;
2. both sides have side effects [MISRA 2012 Rule 1.3, required], [MISRA 2012 Rule 13.2, required]   buf[count] = U1RXREG;

Source code for problem 1:

```
 void UART_call(void)
 {
    if(count < BUF_SIZE)
    {
        buf[count++] = U1RXREG;
        Flag = 1;
    }
    else
    {
        count = 0;
        Flag = 0;
    }
}
```

After resolving 13.3 error from problem 1 code I am getting MISRA 1.3 and 13.2 errors. Source code for problem 2:

```
void UART_call(void)
 {
    if(count < BUF_SIZE)
    {
        buf[count] = U1RXREG;
        count = count + 1U;
        Flag = 1;
    }
    else
    {
        count = 0;
        Flag = 0;
    }
}
```

Comment: The variable count shown in the function UART_call is a global variable. Any modification of count produces a side effect. MISRA is insisting that such side effects are bad in safety critical software.

Comment: how are `buf` and `count` defined ?

Comment: Why are you using global variables and not parameters?

Comment: I don't think there's any point in replacing `count++` by `count = count + 1U`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> 1. increment/decrement operation combined with other operation with side-effects [MISRA 2012 Rule 13.3, advisory]buf[count++] = U1RXREG;

This is as you seem to have noted, solved by moving the incrementation out of the assignment expression:

```
buf[count] = U1RXREG;
count++;
```

The rationale behind this is to prevent writing bugs such as `buf[count++] = count;`

> 2. both sides have side effects [MISRA 2012 Rule 1.3, required], [MISRA 2012 Rule 13.2, required] buf[count] = U1RXREG;

I'd say this is a false positive. The line `buf[count] = U1RXREG;` is harmless.

The reason for the warning is that `U1RXREG` is obviously a volatile-qualified rx register of the UART hardware, and MISRA-C doesn't like mixing volatile access with other things in the same expression, particularly not with another "side-effect", in this case the `++` of count together with the assignment to `buf`. It's a common source for false positives from static analysers, though sometimes they do find real bugs related to this, as in the `&&` case you asked about [yesterday](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54084453/how-to-make-c-code-to-misra-c2012-compliance).

Assuming 32 bit registers, then the pedantic way to fix it is to use a temporary variable:

```
uint32_t rxreg = U1RXREG
buf[count] = rxreg;
```

As far as machine code and program behavior are concerned, this is equivalent to the original code.

Comment: Thanks appreciate your help.

Comment: It doesn't look like a false positive to me. `buf[count++] = count` has undefined behavior, because `count` is read and written without an intervening sequence point. But MISRA 13.3 is intended to prohibit well-defined code that the authors consider potentially confusing, such as `buf[count++] = unrelated_value`.

Comment: @KeithThompson Where did you get `buf[count++] = count` from? It's neither in the question nor this answer. Most of the time 13.3 is sound, there aren't many sound reasons why one would ever mix ++ with assignment expressions.

Comment: @Lundin: No, it's not in the question. It was just an example of undefined behavior. IMHO `buf[count++] = some_value;` is ok, but MISRA disagrees.

Comment: @KeithThompson I think the point is that `for(count=0; count<n; count++) { buf[count] = some_value;` is much better code. And then there's also the volatile access aspect addressed in the answer.